# how to add a conditional statement after calculating two fields in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to output data based on a condition to limit output to usable data. Need help with understanding and optimizing query and removing redundancies for my SQL query

I tried conditions in the where statement, but that is giving me an error. Also tried adding a Having statement, which did not work either.

```
select
  o2.car_move_id as Carrier_Code,
  o1.early_shpdte,
  o1.prtnum,
  shpsts,
  (o1.host_ordqty / o3.untqty) as Order_pallets,
  (
    select
      count(i3.untqty)
    from
      INVENTORY_PCKWRK_VIEW i3
      inner join prtftp_dtl i4 on i3.prtnum = i4.prtnum
    where
      i3.invsts like 'U'
      and i3.wrkref is null
      and i3.prtnum = o1.prtnum
      and i3.untqty = i4.untqty
      and i4.uomcod like 'PL'
      and i4.wh_id like 'RX'
  ) as full_pallets,
  (
    select
      count(i5.untqty)
    from
      INVENTORY_PCKWRK_VIEW i5
      inner join prtftp_dtl i6 on i5.prtnum = i6.prtnum
    where
      i5.invsts like 'U'
      and i5.wrkref is null
      and i5.prtnum = o1.prtnum
      and i5.untqty < i6.untqty
      and i5.prtnum = i6.prtnum
      and i6.uomcod like 'PL'
      and i6.wh_id like 'RX'
  ) as Partial_pallets
from
  ord_line o1
  inner join SHIP_STRUCT_VIEW o2 on o1.ordnum = o2.ship_id
  inner join prtftp_dtl o3 on o1.prtnum = o3.prtnum
where
  o2.ship_id like '0%'
  and shpsts in ('R', 'I')
  and o1.non_alc_flg = 0
  and o3.wh_id like 'RX'
  and o3.uomcod like 'PL'
order by
  full_pallets asc,
  o1.early_shpdte asc
```

I want to only output the query where order_pallets > Full_Pallets. not sure where I can add this condition in my query.

Comment: Edid you post using code formatting tags.

Comment: `WHERE` _clause_, `HAVING` _clause_. _column_, not field.

Answer (score 0):

The items on the `SELECT` list of an SQL query are logically processed *after* the `WHERE` clause (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905893/logical-processing-order-or-sql-standard-in-where-clause)), that's why you cannot reference column aliases in the `WHERE` clause. You will need to use a subselect to accomplish what you want:

```
select * from (
  select
    o2.car_move_id as Carrier_Code,
    o1.early_shpdte,
    o1.prtnum,
    shpsts,
    -- the rest of your current query
) t
where t.order_pallets > t.Full_Pallets
```

Comment: this was really helpful. Thank you

Comment: @AmmarBhotwawala please accept the answer if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose your entire query in

```
with x as ()
```

Then select from it:

```
select * from x 
where x.order_pallets > x.full_pallets
```

This will save you from having to maintain multiple subqueries for the same information.